# I want to split a folder with large number of files

Tags: excel, vba

I am in a strange situation... I get a large number of files (XML or Excel)... I store it in a folder.

But, I need to split it into smaller batches and give it to my team members, so that they can work on those files.

So, I want to create a Macro that can split the folder (for example 1000 files) into about 10 folders with 100 files in each of them.

Is this possible? could you please guide me.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Let us know if you run into any specific problems related to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through a folder in vba: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

It's also possible to create folders using `mkdir`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement

And it's possible to move files from one folder to another, check [this site](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm) (really helpfull site in general by the way)

This should get you going:)

Answer (score -2):

I have seen various versions of shell scripting (including PowerShell) that can split documents themselves (csv, dat, etc.) into many other files.  As well as scripting that can loop through the contents of a directory and archive them, format them, etc.

I don't have a sample readily available, but it is possible to create a script to do such a thing for you.  Now whether you have the admin privileges to execute such a script is another question all together.